# Appengine deploy now has in valid Oauth2 error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, oauth

This is the first question I have asked - I can normally find the answers I need but not this time.

I am trying to deploy to appengine from eclipse and am getting 401 invalid Oauth2 token. To try and fix this I have upgraded to sdk 1.9.19 and was then able to do a appcfg rollback after setting the --Oauth2 and then entered in the code supplied (I could not even do a rollback without the Oauth2 token).

I have found that Google are not allowing updates now from non secure (non Oauth2) apps and it would seem that Eclipse might be in that category. How can I / can I still do uploads to appengine from Eclipse.

This is a new problem, I have been using appengine from eclipse for years.

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: appcfg update creates its staging directory then just hangs. I can do rollbacks though.

Comment: have you tried removing the OAuth authorization form your Google Account settings and adding it again?

Answer (score 0):

It was a timeout. For some reason my upload speed has become much slower. Eventually the files are uploaded after several attempts with rollbacks in between.

Rollbacks do now need the --oauth2 flag on appcfg in case anybody has the same problem.